# Make div extend to fit content

Tags: html, css

I have a div (blue border) contains content. If the content expands, it suddenly does not fit the div. How to I make the div extend so that the content is still contained?

Consider the following demonstration.
Once I expand the collapsible, it goes beyond my nice blue border. Can I extend it?

So far `display:table-cell` might do the job. But this will destroy all the other formatting.

```css
.page {
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 88%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #240ACF;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    background-color: #fffbf9
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 590px;
    height: inherit
}

.accordion .content {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="container" >
        <section class="accordion">
            <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
            <h2 class="handle ">
                <label for="handle2">Click Here</label>
            </h2>
            <div class="content">
                <p>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit.: Minimized example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your code? You need to add code to this question for us to help you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I thought it would be fine to link a website containing the code. Some friendly moderator already copied it over and I will make sure to minimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove all `height` definitions for `.page`, just keep `min-height` and - since the expandable menu has `float: right` - you should prevent floating content from escaping the container. This can be done in multiple ways, e.g. by setting `.page { display: table; }` or `.page { overflow: hidden; }`.

Comment: Thank you!
Removing all 'height' and '.page { display: table; }' is precisely what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
.page {margin-top: 2%;box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #240ACF;margin-bottom: 70px;background-color: #fffbf9}.container {position: relative;width: 590px;height: inherit}.accordion .content {overflow-y: hidden;height: 0;transition: height 0.3s ease;}.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {height: auto;overflow: visible;}

<div class="page">
<div class="container" >
    <section class="accordion">
        <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
        <h2 class="handle ">
            <label for="handle2">Click Here</label>
        </h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br></p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: use this CSS that will work file you should remove height and float.